# Turn sparse matrix to array for use in grid search

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I have a sparse matrix that was produced after passing a `dataframe` with documents in each row to `TfidfVectorizer` and later to `fit_transform`.
Now I am trying to use that in GridSearchCV as an estimator.
Specifically:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = 'english')

vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(df.news)
```

Now, I want to use the `vectors` as an estimator.

```
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True))
alphas = np.array([1,0.1,0.01,0.001,0.0001,0]) 
grid = grid_search.GridSearchCV(estimator = clf,param_grid = dict(alpha=alphas))

grid.fit(vectors, df.type)
```

It returns value error like this:

> ---> 17 grid.fit(vectors, df.type)
>
> ValueError: Invalid parameter alpha for estimator
>   CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=OneVsRestClassifier(estimator=SVC(C=1,
>   cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
>   decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto_deprecated',
>   kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
>   shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False),
>             n_jobs=None),
>               cv='warn', method='sigmoid'). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.

To give you an idea of how these variables look:

```
print(vectors)

(0, 52)     0.026904364115790672
(0, 106)    0.026904364115790672
(0, 135)    0.13452182057895337
(0, 161)    0.026904364115790672
(0, 180)    0.03800386016882953
(0, 241)    0.028098990259356804

 df.type

0       alt.science
1       alt.science
2       alt.science
3       alt.science
4       alt.science
```

What can be the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: If your goal is to transform a sparse matrix in a dense one you can use [toarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray.html) but this could create huge matrix.

Comment: I have already tried that but the error remained.Based on the error does this look like it is the issue?

Comment: please take a look to [GridSearchCV.fit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.fit) the only unnamed parameter is `X` it does not know how to use `df.type` ...